# pine script - multi time frame plotting not working

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot a 4H (240) crossover sum on the daily chart, but it's not working. The crossover is visible when i select the 4H chart, but when i switch it to the daily chart, the crossover sum is gone. Here's my code. I don't know what exactly the problem is. i'd appreciate any assistance. thanks!

```
//@version=4
study(title="MTF Crossover Test", overlay=true)

first = ema(close, 5)
seconds = ema(close, 13)
third = sma(close,21)
fourth = sma(close,34)
fifth = sma(close, 55)
sixth = sma(close,89)


// if long1 or long2 or long3 is true 2 times in the previous 6 six candles then plot it ("long")

longres = input(title = "Long Resolution", type = input.resolution , defval = "240" )

long1 = (first > seconds) and crossover(first,third)
long2 = (first > third) and crossover(first, seconds)
long3 = (first > fourth) and (first > seconds) and (first > third) and cross(first,fourth)
long4 = crossover(first,seconds) and first == third and first == fourth and cross(first,third)

fourcrossover1 = security( syminfo.tickerid, longres, long1 )
fourcrossover2 = security( syminfo.tickerid, longres, long2 )
fourcrossover3 = security( syminfo.tickerid, longres, long3 )
fourcrossover4 = security( syminfo.tickerid, longres, long4 )

LENGTH = 6

countlong = sum(fourcrossover1 or fourcrossover2 or fourcrossover3 or fourcrossover4 ? 1 : 0, LENGTH)

plotshape(countlong >= 2, title="L", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="L", size=size.small)
```

Here are some screenshots:
[image: 4H chart]

[image: 1D chart]

Answer (score 1):

From [Pine Script v4 User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#requesting-data-of-a-lower-timeframe):

> `security` function was designed to request data of a timeframe *higher*
>   than the current chart timeframe. On a *60 minutes* chart, this would
>   mean requesting 240, D, W, or any higher timeframe.
>
> It is not recommended to request data of a timeframe *lower* that the
>   current chart timeframe, for example *1 minute* data from a *5 minutes*
>   chart. The main problem with such a case is that some part of a 1
>   minute data will be inevitably lost, as it’s impossible to display it
>   on a *5 minutes* chart and not to break the time axis. In such cases the
>   behavior of `security` can be rather unexpected.